# Azure Function: What is the best way for me to filter out logs from other Azure Function Apps in "Log Stream"?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am using Service Bus Topic Trigger Azure Function (v4) and have created corresponding Azure Functions for the Service Bus Topic subscriptions. To log my activities, I am utilizing Application Insights.

However, when attempting to monitor logs in "Log Stream," I noticed that it displays logs for all Azure Functions, including those not related to my current function(but configured with same Application Insights). Is there a way to filter out other Service Bus Topic Trigger Function App logs and only monitor the logs for the current Azure Function that I have opened in "Log Stream"?

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason why you can’t monitor the specific function instead? Log stream is for the entire app service. Alternatively, monitor the logs in real time in app insights and filter the relevant operations.

Comment: You can use Custom Logs in Azure Functions to indicate which function you are using.

Comment: You can also use ```traces
| where message contains "FUNCTIONNAME"```

Comment: @Skin, I was able to see same earlier(only opened Function App), but not sure why it is showing other function App's logs as well.

Comment: @Rakesh Kumar, did you try that kusto query  in logs section?

Comment: @RithwikBojja yes, I tried your query as well (traces | where message contains "FUNCTIONNAME"), it is also not giving expected results. It is not showing even single logs from code.

Comment: have you tried my answer below? @Rakesh Kumar

Comment: Try this ```traces 
| where operation_Name contains "FunctionName"```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Azure Function: What is the best way for me to filter out logs from other Azure Function Apps in "Log Stream"?

You could use Logs section , with below query:

```
traces 
| where operation_Name contains "FunctionName"
```

Here the function name is Emo and its logs are:

[image]

Here Function Name is Vammo:

[image]

You can also use Custom Logs for your functions too for easy recognising you function .

Comment: Yes! I am able to filter the logs with your query. (traces 
| where operation_Name contains "FunctionName"), But I am looking for same filter under the "Log Stream",

Comment: Log stream logs are same as this section logs. So this gives same output you want https://i.imgur.com/OHp5MG3.png

Comment: yes! but we can monitor live logs under the "Log Stream". When I trigger any event I usually use "Log Stream" to see the live logs. When we filter using FunctionName it is not showing all the logs which we have added in the code.

Comment: You can check live in https://i.imgur.com/MGo6UWw.png Monitor section of your function. I guess this clear all your doubts.

Comment: For clear understanding https://i.imgur.com/OPbasuO.png

Comment: @RithwikBojja Thanks! for your prompt response, I am able to see logs. But earlier i was able to see only function app specific logs under "Log Stream". As I mentioned earlier now it is showing all other function App logs which are using the same application insights. Not sure why this behavior got changed recently