# Log stream shows logs from other resources

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I am trying to view app insight logs for my Azure Function using the Log Stream but it's showing logs from all apps/functions.

My App Insights account has multiple resources pointing to it but I was expecting to see logs only from the current Function in the Log Stream.

Comment: It shows all logs of all functions in Log stream

Comment: It should only be showing logs from the current resource in the Log Stream. If I wanted to look at all the logs then I can always look at the App Insights account

Comment: Yes, you can check in Live Metrics.

Comment: If you go back to the Log Stream after filtering in Live Metrics then it only shows logs for the current function

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, clicked on "Open in Live Metrics" and then on the Live Metrics blade filtered by the role which is my function resource name. Closed the blade and now the log stream only shows verbose log output from my function only.

Comment: Thank you! This should be the accepted answer. I don't know why such a common sense thing is so not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to view app insight logs for my Azure Function using the Log Stream but it's showing logs from all apps/functions.

Yes, Log Stream show all the logs of all resources which are linked to it.

To check a particular logs of a particular function, you can check in Monitoring Section and then click on logs.

To check the logs of a function named **`rithfunc1`**, use below KQL query:

```
traces 
| where operation_Name contains "rithfunc1"
```

[image]

To check another function you can check like below:

```
traces 
| where operation_Name contains "funcrith2"
```

[image]

As application insights collects all the logs of all apps/functions and then stores, so if you want logs of a particular function follow the KQL query and also refer [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75820861/azure-function-what-is-the-best-way-for-me-to-filter-out-logs-from-other-azure/75821369#75821369)

Comment: Thanks @rithwikbojja but that's not what I am after, I am looking for verbose log information output by the Azure Function.